# Ramification of mod $\ell$ representation of elliptic curves

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $p,\ell$ be two prime numbers.
Consider the mod $\ell$ representation $$\rho:Gal(\mathbb{\overline{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to Aut(E[\ell])= GL(2,\ell).$$
I want to know the results [or references] about the ramification of $\rho$ at different primes $p$.$

For example,  can we know $\rho$ is unramified/tamely remified/wildly ramified at $p$, given conditons such that $E$ has good/mlutipicative reduction at $\ell$ or $p$?

Comment: Cross-posting : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861684/ramification-of-mod-ell-representation-of-elliptic-curves?noredirect=1#comment10363612_4861684

Comment: ... and it has a very good answer there.